# TYPO3 integrating HTML

Tags: html, css, image, templates, typo3

I'm newbie at TYPO3, trying to install my custom template.
I have HTML/CSS/IMAGES files, but can't find how to implement it.

Find file **/fileadmin/default/templates/typo3-intro-template.html** changes on it affects on site.  But I can't understand how to use it to show dynamic content.

When I add this:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
#page.10 = USER
page.10 = TEXT
#page.10.userFunc = tx_templavoila_pi1->main_page
page.10.value = Hello world
```

to page **Setup**, got Hello world, but without design.

Is there any way to add something like:

```
page.10.template = /fileadmin/default/templates/tmy-file.html
```

?

Comment: You should create separate TYPO3 instance just for learning purposes, and give a TemplaVoila One more chance, it will be more useful for you in the future, believe me. TV has a build-in `kickstarter` - if you'll use it and will read carefully on screen messages you'll find your way to make it correct in minutes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it now. Hope it will work.

Comment: TemplaVoila is an outdated concept that is more a hack than a solution. Use `FLUIDTEMLATE`s instead. http://typo3.org/documentation/article/the-fluidtemplate-cobject/ together with backend-layouts, you can have the same flexibility with a much more future proof solution. Also have a look at the `gridelements` extension on top of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of manuals for Typo3. There are 2 choices with templating. Either with Templavoila or with Autoparser. Autoparser is completley scripted and Templavoila uses a graphical interface.

Comment: I tried TemplaViola but got some error about data structure. Will try with AutoPasrer. Thanks.

Comment: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/tutorials/doc_tut_templselect/current/ is the official introduction to "old school" marker based templating together with `automaketemplate`. Once you understood the concept of `TYPO3` and `TypoScript`, you should move on to `FLUIDTEMPLATE` as this is the way to go.

Comment: I don't like Fluidtemplate they use inline syntax like smarty. Is this the new school?

Comment: So what means fluid? Is it infinity scroll? I still doesn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an overview of setting up a site with TemplaVoila:  http://webdevelopers.thedemo.ca/

We'll move to fluid in the future, but for now this method is tried and true, and not going anywhere for a while.

I don't like the way fluid uses inline syntax either.

Answer (score 1):

```
config {
  baseURL = http://www.bla.com/
  prefixLocalAnchors = all
  meaningfulTempFilePrefix=1
  doctype=xhtml_trans
  htmlTag_langKey=de
  remove_defaultJS=external
  inlineStyle2TempFile=1
  disablePrefixComment = 1
  linkVars=L
  sys_language_uid=0
  language=en
  locale_all = en_EN.UTF-8
  xmlprologue = none
}

page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.bodyTag=<body>
page.10=TEMPLATE
page.10 {
    template = FILE
    template.file = fileadmin/templates/template.html
    workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT
    subparts  {
            CONTENT=COA
            CONTENT.10<styles.content.get
    }
}
```

template file:

```
<!-- ###DOCUMENT### -->

<!-- ###CONTENT### -->CONTENT<!-- ###CONTENT### -->

<!-- ###DOCUMENT### -->
```