# Complete control over HTML output from TYPO3

Tags: html, angularjs, templates, typo3

I'm setting up an site in TYPO3 that ues AngularJS. To get the right CSS class on body I need to edit the `<body>` tag. I also want to have complete control over the HTML output from my template.

My current attempt was to use a template configured from backend:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEMPLATE
page.10.template = FILE
page.10.template.file = fileadmin/Template/index.html
```

This outputs the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- 
    This website is powered by TYPO3 - inspiring people to share!
    TYPO3 is a free open source Content Management Framework initially created by Kasper Skaarhoj and licensed under GNU/GPL.
    TYPO3 is copyright 1998-2014 of Kasper Skaarhoj. Extensions are copyright of their respective owners.
    Information and contribution at http://typo3.org/
-->

<title>My site - Title from Typo3</title>
<meta name="generator" content="TYPO3 6.2 CMS">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typo3temp/stylesheet_8b9c2e8d89.css?1418032603" media="all">

</head>
<body>

<!-- HTML basics -->
<!-- My template start here -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" ng-app="app"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8" ng-app="app"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="ie lt-ie9" ng-app="app"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html ng-app="app"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My site - Title from template</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" CONTENT="noindex, nofollow">
```

The [Templates guide in documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/GettingStartedTutorial/Templates/Index.html) does not tell advanced stuff like switching out the whole template for something else.

- Can I use an extension for this?
- Can I create an extension for my template?
- How can my template create the TYPO3 placeholders where content is added?

I would like to have my template and CSS/Javascript in repository, not configured in backend GUI (database).

Related question: [TYPO3 integrating HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070405/typo3-integrating-html)

Comment: You have many different questions in your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another, less known solution for the "full control over template" issue

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#pagerenderertemplatefile

```
config.pageRendererTemplateFile = my/path/template.html
```

Then you can copy the template from typo3/sysext/tslib/template/tslib_page_frontend.html and edit it to your needs, e.g.

```
###XMLPROLOG_DOCTYPE###
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="de" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="de" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="de" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="de" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> 
  <html lang="de" class="no-js"> 
<!--<![endif]-->
###HEADTAG###

###METACHARSET###
###INLINECOMMENT###

###BASEURL###
###SHORTCUT###
###TITLE###
###META###

###CSS_INCLUDE###
###CSS_INLINE###

###JS_LIBS###
###JS_INCLUDE###
###JS_INLINE###

###HEADERDATA###
</head>
###BODY###
###JS_LIBS_FOOTER###
###JS_INCLUDE_FOOTER###
###JS_INLINE_FOOTER###
###FOOTERDATA###
</body>
</html>
```

If this is really robust (I have it on one site and there have been no problems), the advantage over `config.disableAllHeaderCode` is that - for example - you will still have the ability to get default JS included, like the decrypt function for `config.spamProtectEmailAddresses`, which else, you have to add manually.

To output a RSS feed, I would prefer `config.disableAllHeaderCode` too, but if it's about outputting a HTML document, this may be a viable option.

> Can I create an extension for my template?

It is considered a good practice now to keep templates in an extension. I personally still have them in `fileadmin/templates/myproject`

> How can my template create the TYPO3 placeholders where content is added?

Please refer to the links in @pgampe's answer. You can start directly with FLUIDTEMPLATE, so you will learn the most current templating language. It's necessary to read a few basic documents to get started with TYPO3.

> I would like to have my template and CSS/Javascript in repository, not configured in backend GUI (database).

You are right, and that's the best practice too, see @pgampe's links. In the DB, you then only have.

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/main/ts/config.ts">
```

or even (do I get that right?):

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE: EXT:mytemplateext/path/to/config.ts">
```

and so on. Including TypoScript also works for Page TSConfig AND User TSConfig. I wouldn't want to work in any other way!

You'll also want to get code coloring for your favourite editor, e.g. for Sublime here: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/TypoScript

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reading the `Getting Started Guide`, you should try the `Templating Tutorial`: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TemplatingTutorial/

You can exclude all your TS into files and include this inside only one template record. This is what the `Introduction Package` is doing.
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/Syntax/Includes/Index.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create any extension, as it's possible to disable it easily with TypoScript (Setup field)

```
config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1
```

[@See the docs](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#disableallheadercode)

of course in such case, you need to add all the header into your template.

Also this flag is usefull, when you want to render i.e. pure JSON (or other data) from your Extbase ext included to the specifig `typeNum` via bootsrtap